Predicting next elements with an LSTM, based on previous ones, or even based on no previouse ones
I have a time series problem, which consists of predicting prices with an LSTM. The dataset is imported from the Python library yfinance. I used the example code in a geeks for geeks tutorial built in Pytorch, and managed to understand everything. The only concrete part I think I don't understand can be seen on this code snippet:
# Define the number of future time steps to forecast
num_forecast_steps = 30

# Convert to NumPy and remove singleton dimensions
sequence_to_plot = X_test.squeeze().cpu().numpy()

# Use the last 30 data points as the starting point
historical_data = sequence_to_plot[-1]
print(historical_data.shape)

# Initialize a list to store the forecasted values
forecasted_values = []

# Use the trained model to forecast future values
with torch.no_grad():
    for _ in range(num_forecast_steps*2):
        # Prepare the historical_data tensor
        historical_data_tensor = torch.as_tensor(historical_data).view(1, -1, 1).float().to(device)
        # Use the model to predict the next value
        predicted_value = model(historical_data_tensor).cpu().numpy()[0, 0]

        # Append the predicted value to the forecasted_values list
        forecasted_values.append(predicted_value[0])

        # Update the historical_data sequence by removing the oldest value and adding the predicted value
        historical_data = np.roll(historical_data, shift=-1)
        historical_data[-1] = predicted_value

        
# Generate futute dates
last_date = test_data.index[-1]

# Generate the next 30 dates
future_dates = pd.date_range(start=last_date + pd.DateOffset(1), periods=30)

# Concatenate the original index with the future dates
combined_index = test_data.index.append(future_dates)

Also, the code for the model:
class LSTMModel(nn.Module):
    # input_size : number of features in input at each time step
    # hidden_size : Number of LSTM units 
    # num_layers : number of LSTM layers 
    def __init__(self, input_size, hidden_size, num_layers): 
        super(LSTMModel, self).__init__() #initializes the parent class nn.Module
        self.lstm = nn.LSTM(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers, batch_first=True)
        self.linear = nn.Linear(hidden_size, 1)

    def forward(self, x): # defines forward pass of the neural network
        out, _ = self.lstm(x)
        out = self.linear(out)
        return out

input_size = 1
num_layers = 2
hidden_size = 64
output_size = 1

# Define the model, loss function, and optimizer
model = LSTMModel(input_size, hidden_size, num_layers).to(device)

loss_fn = torch.nn.MSELoss(reduction='mean')

optimizer = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=1e-3)
print(model)

Based on what is on the tutorial, rolling prediction is used. That means, if I'm right, an array with input elements is used as a window for predicting the next element, which is appended to the window, for predicting the next one, and so on. My problem might have to do with the concept or other parts of the code, but I don't really understand  this line of code:
# Append the predicted value to the forecasted_values list
forecasted_values.append(predicted_value[0])

If I would like to predict the next element based on 30 previous ones, why should I take the first predicted element of the prediction array? (which for me means the second element of the 30 previous ones input sequence). How could I modify this example if I would need to build a sequence window based on values being generated on the fly, and not having previous elements before?
PS: Below there is a screenshot showing a plot from a prediction.

It's impossible to say without the model code. You are indexing into predicted_value multiple times - predicted_value = model(historical_data_tensor).cpu().numpy()[0, 0] and forecasted_values.append(predicted_value[0]). This can mean a lot of things depending on how the model constructs the output

@Karl I edited the question by adding the information you asked for, thanks for your answer.
